# Why do we initially set min and max to the first value in the array when trying to find the minimum and maximum value?

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I've been learning Java for a while and I've run into a problem I can't figure out. I am currently learning arrays and how to iterate through them using loops. I generally understand how the if statement and the for loop work, but in this case I don't understand the principle of this loop in combination with if statements. This is the example I'm talking about:

```java
class MinMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int nums[] = new int[10];
        int min, max;

        nums[0] = 99;
        nums[1] = -10;
        nums[2] = 100123;
        nums[3] = 18;
        nums[4] = -978;
        nums[5] = 5623;
        nums[6] = 463;
        nums[7] = -9;
        nums[8] = 287;
        nums[9] = 49;

        min = max = nums[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++){
            if (nums[i] < min) min = nums[i];
            if (nums[i] > max) max = nums[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Largest and smallest value: " + min + " " + max);

    }
}
```

I want to focus on this part:

```java
        min = max = nums[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++){
            if (nums[i] < min) min = nums[i];
            if (nums[i] > max) max = nums[i];
```

The only thing I understand from this is how this for loop works, but the instruction `min = max = nums[0];` is unclear to me. Why are we assigning these values to each other? Probably because I don't understand this instruction I also can't understand the principle of if statements in this example.

Can someone explain it to me step by step please?

Comment: Please understand that this isn't programming school. We aren't *teaching* here. And the real point is: when you do not understand what your code is doing ... then simply add more print statements. You print min AFTER the loop ... why not `if (nums[i]<min) { min = ... ; System.out.println(print i, min, nums[i] ... ); } ` (pseudo code, adapt as needed)

Comment: Also: another approach is: take a piece of paper, and a pen. Then "run" the code in your mind. Write down the values of all variables, and then go over the code line by line. Write down what changes, write down what gets compared, assigned, and so on.

Comment: *"`min = max = nums[0]`"* — I have to say that I would refrain from writing constructs like these, especially if I were teaching folks the Java language. Instead, I would just use two statements.

Comment: Hi&Welcome! The "correct"(mathematical) initialization would be: a (hilariously) high value for "min" , and accordingly low value for "max". Doing `min=max=nums[0]`, just (correctly) skips the first (`i=0`) iteration/if. (Correct, when nums.length>0, and nums[0] in "valid range";)

Comment: One more advantage (of this initialization): you could sneak in an `else` between the `if`s ..which would "little safe" !;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min = max = nums[0];
```

is simply a short way of writing

```
min = nums[0];
max = nums[0];
```

because the "value" of an assignment is equal to the value being assigned. Which means that `max = nums[0]` evaluates to the same value as `nums[0]`. So the line of code could be rewritten like this to make the meaning slightly more obvious:

```
min = (max = nums[0]);
```

And why this is done is simple: the "current minimum" and "current maximum" is often set to the first value of a non-empty list before the loop, because we know that the true minimum is *at most* as much as the value of the first element and the true maximum is *at least* as much as the value of the first element.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we initially set min and max to the first value in the array when trying to find the minimum and maximum value?

You don't have to set `min` and `max` to the first value.  It is simply a way to find the values more efficiently since they must be one of those values so simply assign the first one.  So you just `assume` that they are both `min` and `max` and the proceed to start with the next value in the array and alter `min` and `max` accordingly.

```
min = max = nums[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++){
       if (nums[i] < min) min = nums[i];
       if (nums[i] > max) max = nums[i];
}
```

You could also do it like this.

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int v : nums) {
   if (v < min) {
      min = v;
   }
   if (v > max) {
      max = v;
   }
}
```

In the above case, you are iterating over *all the values* so you can use the enhanced for loop.  I also wrote it using curly braces for a single statement which, imo, is a good practice to help avoiding careless mistakes and inadvertently introducing bugs.

Answer (score -1):

It is the teacher's way of combining different aspects to see if you can understand all concepts that have already been taught.

It would be clearer to be more explicit and I would certainly iterate on all items instead of skipping the first item:

```java
min = 0; // default min to 0
max = 0; // default max to 0
// iterate on ALL items in the array, starting at 0 till last element
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++) {
    if (nums[i] < min) min = nums[i];
    if (nums[i] > max) max = nums[i];
}
```

Comment: Setting `min` to 0 initially means that it will never change if all the values are > 0. Similarly for `max` if all the values are negative. If you want to set the values to something other than an element of `nums`, then you must use something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`/`Integer.MIN_VALUE`.